# Creating entity fields based on the fields from another entity

Tags: 8, entities

I've been trying to create a data structure that resembles something like:

```
            +-----------+-----------+-----------+
            | Service 1 | Service 2 | Service x |
            +-----------+-----------+-----------+
            |  Price 1  |  Price 2  |  Price x  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| Feature 1 |    Yes    |    Yes    |    Yes    | Description 1 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| Feature 2 |     1     |     6     |    20     | Description 2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| Feature x |    No     |    No     |    Yes    | Description x |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

I've created a content entity `Services`, which has the following fields:

1. Service Name
2. Price
3. Feature 1
4. Feature 2
5. Feature x

This works great, until I realise that I'm not including the descriptions of each feature.

Drawing on my knowledge of database normalisation, I intend to extrapolate the description and feature to its own content entity, `Services Info`. I think that would probably work just fine, with one small exception, I now need to maintain the list of features in two entities, something I'm loathed to do.

Is there any way I can get Drupal to synchronise the fields across two tables? So that if/when I add more features to the `Services` entity, it'll appear in the `Services Info` entity, waiting for me to input a description for it?

Or, if there's a better, more Drupally way to approach this problem, then please feel free to chime in!

**UPDATE**:

I realise that my question might not be clear enough, so I thought I'd explain what I'd do if I weren't using Drupal to make this...

I'd have the following SQL tables:

tbl_services:

```
SERVICE NAME (FK)
FEATURE NAME (FK)
SERVICE FEATURE VALUE
```

tbl_services_info:

```
SERVICE NAME (PK)
PRICE
```

tbl_services_features:

```
FEATURE NAME (PK)
FEATURE DESCRIPTION
FEATURE RECOMMENDED
```

... Now I'm looking at it, I guess I'm missing an entity..? Which if I introduced I could have them reference each other correctly?

If I were to implement it this way I'd also have the issue of not being able to REQUIRE that **ALL** `SERVICE NAMEs` have **ALL** `SERVICE FEATURE VALUEs` declared for **ALL** `FEATURE NAMEs`... Could I? Or would I just have to create a custom input form for the entities?

Comment: I don't understand the structure, can you show how you implemented this in Drupal terms? (base/bundle fields, field types, single/multi value). How does feature x scale (if x is a placeholder)?. If this is unlimited, then why not use a tag style reference to a taxonomy vocabulary `feature` (which would have a description field by default).

Comment: The structure I'm looking for is that I can add as many `services` as needed. Each service has a set of `features`, of which, each `service` can store some data against (true, false, 0, 35, 'dog', 'cat', etc)... Then I also need to store additional data about the `features` themselves (a description, importance, etc.)... I want the `feature` to be the "question" for the `services` entity, and then in a view be able to display the description associated with that `feature`, along with the `feature` name, and anything else that may be relevant. As well as if the particular `service` has it.

Comment: Still looks like you need a reference field, which defines a one-to-many relationship between services and features. Should work like a content type containing a taxonomy term field to a vocabulary, which both are fieldable and can contain as much data as you need.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by, "which both are fieldable"... I have made a `feature` vocabulary, but a `service` will have a value for EVERY `feature`. If you look at the table I drew in the OP, I will create services (Service 1, etc), and I need to say what value it has for a given feature. Not simply if it has a given feature, as a feature might be a value, not just a boolean.

Comment: You mean like a node has a title for each image stored in the node, not in the image, so that the same image can have different titles? Then you need either a custom field type with multiple properties like the image field or use a paragraph to group the feature reference field with the additional data fields.

Comment: I've updated my question to try and make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to "listen" for the creation of entities of type `Services`, and upon creation, you want to programmatically create another of type `Services Info`. For that, I'd recommend adding the [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.3.x) hook into your custom module. Replace `hook` and `ENTITY_TYPE` with your custom module name and entity type, of course.

The function signature will include `$entity` as a variable, so you can do any sort of tests you want to do on it (for example, make sure the corresponding Services Info entry hasn't already been created, to avoid a possible infinite loop if you ever decide to write the sync for both entity types).

This method will look something like:

```
function my_module_services_insert($entity) {

  // If desired, add code here to check for pre-existing mathing Services Info; this will depend on your implementation.
  // For example, if name is unique, run an entity query for services_info entities with a matching name.

  $new_entity_fields = [
    'name' => $entity->getName(), // This assumes you want the entry to have the same name as the Services entry; change if desired
    // Other fields as desired
  ];
  $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('services_info'); // replace 'services_info' with your entity type
  $entity_new = $storage[$content_type]->create($new_entity_fields);
  $entity_new->save();
}
```

That should do the trick. Good luck!